# insufficient permission while posting youtube videos from android using youtube api

Tags: android, youtube, comments

i have a android app that requires comments to be posted from my application to a youtube video. I'm using AccountManager to get the Logged in user and the access Token but when i use the access token or api key to post the comment i get a reply "insufficient permission". Code is as follows.

private void insertVideoComments() {

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp
                    .newCompatibleTransport();
            final JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();

            AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext()).getAuthTokenByFeatures("com.google", "oauth2:https://gdata.youtube.com", null, PlayYoutubeVideosActivity.this,
                    null, null, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

                        @Override
                        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                           Callback");
                            try {
                                Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
                                acc_name = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                                token = bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);

                                Log.d("test", "name: " + acc_name + "; token: " + token);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e("test", e.getClass().getSimpleName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    }, null);

            String url[] = {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"};
            List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList(url);
            GoogleAccountCredential credential;
            GoogleCredential CREDENTIAL = new GoogleCredential();

            credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(PlayYoutubeVideosActivity.this,
                    Arrays.asList(url));

            credential.setSelectedAccountName(acc_name);
            CREDENTIAL.setAccessToken(token);

            youtube = new YouTube.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, credential).setApplicationName(
                    ConstantsRT.APP_NAME).setHttpRequestInitializer(CREDENTIAL)
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(ConstantsRT.CLIENT_KEY))
                    .build();

            CommentSnippet commentSnippet = new CommentSnippet();
            commentSnippet.setTextOriginal("This is for the news");

            //creating top level comment
            Comment topLevelComment = new Comment();
            topLevelComment.setSnippet(commentSnippet);
            // Insert video comment

            CommentThreadSnippet commentThreadSnippet = new CommentThreadSnippet();
            commentThreadSnippet.setVideoId(videoPath);
            commentThreadSnippet.setTopLevelComment(topLevelComment);

            CommentThread commentThread = new CommentThread();
            commentThread.setSnippet(commentThreadSnippet);

            try {
                CommentThread videoCommentInsertResponse = youtube.commentThreads()
                        .insert("snippet", commentThread).setKey(ConstantsRT.API_KEY).execute();
                // Print information from the API response.
                System.out
                        .println("\n================== Created Video Comment ==================\n");
                CommentSnippet snippet = videoCommentInsertResponse.getSnippet().getTopLevelComment()
                        .getSnippet();
                Log.d("test","  - Author: " + snippet.getAuthorDisplayName());
                Log.d("test","  - Comment: " + snippet.getTextDisplay());
                Log.d("test","\n-------------------------------------------------------------\n");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute((Void[]) null);`
```

Comment: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

Comment: which key you are using android key or browser key?

Comment: using an Android Key

Comment: check with Browser key

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is some issue with token as this error come only when -

```
 The OAuth 2.0 token provided for the request specifies scopes that are insufficient for accessing the requested data.
```

Referenced link -

```
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors
```

Comment: So how do i go about it?? how do i get the right token??

Comment: Is both client ID and Client Secret essential in this case??